# OpenSSL difference between v3_req and req_ext

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

What is the difference between the two OpenSSL extensions `v3_req` and `req_ext` ?

Not able to obtain information about them using online search.

Configuration directives:

```
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
#req_extensions      = req_ext
req_extensions      = v3_req
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are simply names that refer to sections that need to be defined in the same config file. The sections are marked with `[` and `]`. `v3_req` is defined in the [OpenSSL config file](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/baba1545105131fa34068f62928322e99d695ab1/apps/openssl.cnf#L219) as:

```
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
```

The commented out line is not found in the official OpenSSL config file. It was probably left there as placeholder to indicate how one would set an extension.

Comment: So you mean `v3_req` is just a placeholder and I could also name it `asdasdasd` ?

Comment: Correct, as long as you have a section named that.